# github: retaining imgs uploaded using paperclip when pushing an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, github, paperclip

I'm currently testing in staging environment (heroku) where I have testers uploading imgs for their profiles using paperclip. However, whenever I do a git push to heroku to update the site (not changing the db), their pictures disappear. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get around this?

Here's my configuration for paperclip:

```
 has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:thumb => "115x100#", :medium => "345x300#", :large => "690x600#"},
                        :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                        :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

production.rb config:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use heroku's filesystem that way.  They intend for you to use S3 or some other durable storage medium.  Heroku calls their filesystem an [Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).  Your application can write to it, but writes aren't visible to other processes and if your dyno restarts all changes are lost.

Paperclip has good support for S3.  Just have a look at [their docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).